# AsRock Z77 Extreme6, D7 no inputs error, no post

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard

Up until recently my z77 had been working perfectly with 2 7950s. Suddenly the board began giving me the D7, no inputs found error at boot and would not post. I have tried continuously with other various cards in every slot and received the same error. I have tried clearing the CMOS, any solutions. Should I RMA?  I accidentally broke the locking pins on two of the graphics card slots, will AsRock make an issue of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely this seemed to resolve itself.  I let it be and it worked a few days later with the same methods I was trying.